# How can I access the class attribute name via the class itself to improve readability and type hinting in Python?

Tags: python, django, python-class

Suppose you have the following classes:

```
class MyClass:
    attribute1: str
    attribute2: int


class MySecondClass:
    another_attribute1: str
    another_attribute2: int
```

I want to access the string `'attribute1'` via the `MyClass` class. For example `MyClass.attribute1.fieldname`, but I am cannot find such an option. If something like this is possible, could you please let me know? I will explain two possible use cases below:

**Use case 1**

Suppose I want to create method which updates an instance of `MyClass` with an instance of `MySecondClass`. It should return a boolean indicating whether the instance of `MyClass` is updated. I would like to put all the fields I want to map in a dictionary so I can loop over them. E.g.

```
my_class_instance: MyClass
my_second_class_instance: MySecondClass

field_map = {
    'attribute1': 'another_attribute1',
    'attribute2': 'another_attribute2'
}

updated = False
for field1, field2 in field_map.items():
    current_value = getattr(my_class_instance, field1)
    new_value = getattr(my_second_class_instance, field2)

    if current_value != new_value:
        setattr(my_class_instance, field, new_value)
        updated = True

return updated
```

The main issue that I have with this solution is that it does not take advantage of type hinting or the power of my IDE when I refactor this code. If I would rename `attribute1` to `attribute_one` on the `MyClass` class, the code would break because `field_map` is not automatically updated. Working with the dictionary makes introducing bugs easier and makes it more tedious to update this code as you have to copy and paste the exact attribute names instead of relying on your good friend, the IDE. You could of course solve this by rewriting the logic to:

```
updated = False
if my_class_instance.attribute1 != my_second_class_instance.another_attribute1:
   my_class_instance.attribute1 = my_second_class_instance.another_attribute1
   updated = True

if my_class_instance.attribute2 != my_second_class_instance.another_attribute2:
   my_class_instance.attribute2 = my_second_class_instance.another_attribute2
   updated = True

return updated
```

but you can easily see how this will get quite ugly when there are a lot of fields to compare.

**Use case 2**

One of the one big issues I have with Django and Django Rest Framework is the use of plain strings all over the place. If you have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.FloatField()
    field2 = models.IntegerField()
```

Your serializer looks something like this:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field1', 'field2']
```

Now again, fields is an array of strings. Especially during development it quite often happens that I rename a field. If I rename `field1` to `my_client_changed_the_requirements`, the serializer breaks because the `fields` array is not updated. If I could construct the `fields` like this:

```
fields = [MyModel.field1.fieldname, MyModel.field2.fieldname]
```

I would benefit

1. from my IDE updating the fields array when I rename a field on `MyModel`
2. from my IDE displaying all the available fields on `MyModel` when I'm writing or updating the fields array.

The same issue applies to the filtering on the Django ORM.

**CONCLUSION**

Please tell me how I can do this now or how I can add this feature to the Python language :)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the field name as a string by using `.field.name` on it, like so: `MyClass.attribute1.field.name`. This will output `"attribute1"`.

---

> but I am cannot find such an option. If something like this is possible, could you please let me know?

On a side note, you can use the built-in [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function to know the possible methods/attributes of any object. Like so:

```
>> dir(MyClass.attribute1)
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__eq__',
 ..
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_check_parent_chain',
 'field']  # Here's the `field` attribute

>> dir(MyClass.attribute1.field)
['__class__',
 '__copy__',
 '__deepcopy__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 ..
 'many_to_one',
 'max_length',
 'merge_dicts',
 'model',
 'name',   # Here's the `name` attribute
 'verbose_name']
```

Comment: Thanks! For Django models this works. For plain Python classes however I think it does not. When trying to access MyClass.attribute1.field.name I run into an AttributeError, because either attribute1 is not defined or field is not defined on attribute1.